# View transition without using navigation controller?

Tags: iphone, viewcontroller

I want to implement  view transition without using navigation controller like pushviewController mechanism. So, I created the view hierarchy like below. 
window is superview and contains three subviews.

```
[window] - aViewController - bViewController - cViewController
```

If I want to go back to the aVewiController from cViewController,  I simply allocate  aViewController again like this: `[[aViewController alloc] init]`.

Then, after 4 circulations, I got `didReceiveMemoryWarning` and "Program exited with status value:0" messages. Its obviously memory issue but no memory leak. Allocating viewcontroller over and over is a problem. I have no idea how to transit view in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your hierarchy of UIViewControllers to behave as they do in UINavigationController case you should

A) show your new ViewController with this call

```
//This code should be implemented in viewControllerA
[self presentModalViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES]
```

B) go back one step by calling

```
//This code should be implemented in viewControllerA
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

Notes: The way you would tell viewControllerA that you want to close viewControllerB is by sending a NSNotification. The good thing about this is that if you want to go from viewControllerC to viewControllerA you simply send a notification to viewControlerA to dissmisModalViewController and it will recursively dismiss viewControllerC and viewControllerB for you.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You should allocate them only once and transition between the views itself by hiding/unhiding them:

viewController.view.hidden = YES/NO;

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure you are releasing your object after you add them to their superview. and Make sure that you are removing them from their superview when they are sent off screen....

If you want to reuse the object then you can keep them in a list and try to dequeue them like the table view does. This way you wont have to remake them each time.

If you add them to the subview and never remove them. then you will have multiple views that are no longer used that are still being referenced by their super view. therefore they will still be in memory.